# PostgreSQL - No records returned with INNER JOIN but INNER JOIN is working with MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have migrated some tables and table data from MS SQL Server to PostgreSQL. The Data on both the sides is identical. However, when I am trying to query two tables using INNER JOIN in MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL the results are different.

With MS SQL Server , I am getting the more than 18K records whereas in PostgreSQL no record is returned !

I know this is weird and it seems to be something related to either syntax or some configuration that I am missing on the PostgreSQL side. I am using pgAdmin4 for querying my PostgreSQL database and SSMS 2018 for querying MS SQL Server database respectively.

Here's my queries -

**PostgreSQL**

```
select * 
from dbo.foo AS fo
INNER join dbo.woo AS wo
on 'fo.ID' = 'wo.ORDERID'
```

Also tried this way but its still giving me no records

```
select * 
from dbo.foo INNER JOIN dbo.woo
on 'foo.ID' = 'woo.OrderID'
```

**MS SQL Server**

```
select * 
from foo
INNER JOIN woo
on foo.ID = woo.OrderID
```

Not sure where the problem lies. Can anyone please suggest something ?

Comment: help us to create sample here in https://dbfiddle.uk/ by selecting postgrey sql

Comment: why you add it in a string `'foo.ID' = 'woo.OrderID'` it shouldn't be a string, remove the quotes **`'`** and try again, and tell us the result

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed Removing the quotes gives 'column foo.id does not exist' error, this issue was something that I was facing in the beginning.

Comment: @ManojRawat open your terminal and enter **`psql`** then `\d table_name` and if you didn't find the column with the name `id` then you should **DROP** the table and recreate it, try and tell me what happened.

Comment: you probably need `foo."ID" = woo."OrderID"` then - identifiers are quoted using double quotes in SQL

Comment: Thank you all, the problem was with the column name "OrderID" which needs to be used as  "orderid" as postgreSQL is case sensitive. I am able to fix run the query and get the results.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing strings and the result is false because 'fo.ID' is different from 'wo.ORDERID'.

You have to write :

```
select * 
from dbo.foo AS fo
INNER join dbo.woo AS wo
on fo.ID = wo.ORDERID
```

or if the table has been created with double quotes

```
select * 
from dbo.foo AS fo
INNER join dbo.woo AS wo
on fo."ID" = wo."ORDERID"
```

Comment: It gives me 'column foo.id does not exist' error.

Comment: Then choose a column that does exist.

Comment: I have modified my answer. I think that you have created your table with double quotes for the column names.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove it from the quotes **`'`** because `'foo.ID'` does not equal `'woo.OrderID'` string, and for `column foo.id does not exist` error, check if the column is exist by entering in your terminal **`psql dbname -U username --password`** replace the `dbname` and `username` to the real credintainls, then `\d table_name` if you don't find the `id` column `DROP` the table and recreate it.